# Best way to quickly and effectively drop a database and delete all files?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I set a Microsoft SQL Server database to offline and drop it, it will be deleted, but the log and data files will remain. If I do it in online mode, there is a chance that another connection will stop me from dropping it. In a dev environment, or for a database that I want to periodically blow away and recreate on production, what's the best sequence of T-SQL commands to blow away a database, along with its data files and log files, that will work as long as I have sa privileges and no one is maliciously trying to stop me from dropping the database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you are in the context of the database, you can't ensure you are the only one using it. Also, don't use batch separators. Run it all as a single batch.

```
Use AlwaysEncryptedSample;

ALTER DATABASE AlwaysEncryptedSample SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

Use master;

DROP DATABASE AlwaysEncryptedSample;
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! Does not using the batch separator actually guarantee another user can't establish a connection to the database or does it just shrink the window for such a race condition?  Most of the time I run scripts like this on my laptop, but I'd like to know the internals of what's going on.

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: We really need a `DROP DATABASE [Blah] WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE | # SECONDS;`

Comment: I have mentioned that same thing on the MVP discussion list. SMO has a KILL method for a database that does all that for you.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following sequence:

1. Switch to *master* (or *tempdb* or any other database besides the one I want to drop)
2. Force the database offline
3. Set it online
4. Drop the database:

   ```
   USE master;
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE AlwaysEncryptedSample 
       SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE AlwaysEncryptedSample SET ONLINE;
   GO
   DROP DATABASE AlwaysEncryptedSample;
   GO
   ```

The problem is if some process is constantly attaching to that database, it becomes a race condition and might not work.

Comment: Your script does **not** need to be split into multiple batches; you should remove the "GO" lines. Additionally, you *technically* don't have to "USE master;". When you switch to OFFLINE, it'll kick you over to "master" automatically (with this warning: "Failed to restart the current database. The current database is switched to master.").